# C# program trouble with errors

Tags: c#

Need help with my code, not sure how to fix returns error CS0102  C# The type already contains a definition lines 91 and 103
Write a C# console application named GirlScout that contains fields for a GirlScout's name, troop number, and dues owed.  Include a constant static field that contains the last words of the GirlScout motto ("to obey the Girl Scout law").  Include overloaded constructors that allow you to set all three nonstatic GirlScout fields to default values or to parameter values.  Also include properties for each field.  Create a class named DemoScouts that instantiates two GirlScout objects and displays their values.  Create one object to use the default constructor and the other to use the constructor that requires arguments.  Also display the GirlScout motto

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoScouts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            GirlScout scout1 = new GirlScout("Carina", 100, 12.50);
            GirlScout scout2 = new GirlScout("Jolene", 103, 23.56);
            GirlScout scout3 = new GirlScout("Karen", 105, 34.43);
            GirlScout scout4 = new GirlScout("Kim", 145, 5.25);
            GirlScout scout5 = new GirlScout("Heather", 200, 1.50);
            GirlScout scout6 = new GirlScout();

            GirlScout objScout1 = new GirlScout();
            objScout1.Name = "YYYYY";
            objScout1.TroopNumber = "1211";
            objScout1.DuesOwed = 2111.12;

            GirlScout objScout2 = new GirlScout("XXX", "232", 123.23);

            //Displaying Scout 1
            Console.WriteLine("Scout 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + objScout1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Troop Number : " + objScout1.TroopNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Dues Owed : " + objScout1.DuesOwed);
            Console.WriteLine("Motto : " + GirlScout.motto);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            //Displaying Scout 2
            Console.WriteLine("Scout 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + objScout2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Troop Number : " + objScout2.TroopNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Dues Owed : " + objScout2.DuesOwed);
            Console.WriteLine("Motto : " + GirlScout.motto);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class GirlScout
    {
        private string name;
        private string TroopNumber;
        private double DuesOwed;
        public static string motto = " Girl Scout Motto";
        private string v1;
        private int v2;
        private double v3;
        private string troopNumber;
        private double duesOwed;

        public GirlScout()
        {
            name = string.Empty;
            troopNumber = string.Empty;
            duesOwed = 0.0;
        }

        public GirlScout(string strName, string strNumber, double dues)
        {
            name = strName;
            troopNumber = strNumber;
            duesOwed = dues;
        }

        public GirlScout(string v1, int v2, double v3)
        {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
            this.v3 = v3;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string TroopNumber
        {
            get { return troopNumber; }
            set { troopNumber = value; }
        }

        public double DuesOwed
        {
           get { return duesOwed; }
           set { duesOwed = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Read the full error message; it says more than what you told us. Search for the names the error message tells you your class “already contains”. Names in a class have to be unique because otherwise the compiler, and you, can't tell which name you mean when you use one.

Comment: You might consider auto-properties on your GirlScout class.  It will reduce the number of backing fields and could make it easier to work with..

Answer (score 4):

You mistakenly defined two fields `troupNumber` and `duesOwned`, first by using capital letters – so they clash with the property defined later – and then correctly in lower case.

Just omit

```
private string TroopNumber;
private double DuesOwed;
```

between `name` and `motto` and everything should be fine.

As a side note you could use auto-properties and skip the fields entirely, by writing:

```
public string TroupNumber { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
private string troupNumber;

public string TroupNumber
{
  { get { return troupNumber; }
  { set { troupNumber = value; }
}
```

As a side note: going by the second non-empty constructor it looks like `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are identical to `name`, `troopNumber` and `duesOwed` with the only difference that `v2` is an int instead of a string.

As you use this constructor which fills the v fields, but output Name, TroupNumber and DuesOwed nothing will show for objects created with the constructor with the v arguments.

This can be remedied by defining the constructor as

```
public void GirlScout(string name, int troupNumber, double duesOwed)
{
  Name = name;
  TroupNumber = troupNumber.ToString();
  DuesOwed = duesOwed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add method with default values provided and have it removed from the constructor:

```
public void GirlScout(string name = string.Empty, int troupNumber = 0, double duesOwed = 0.0)
{
  Name = name;
  TroupNumber = troupNumber.ToString();
  DuesOwed = duesOwed;
}
```